# Getting data fom UI form

Tags: magento-2.1, forms, ui

I have the following question: how can I get data from the UI form directly to the controller? I saw some ways to save data with the button's features, but I don't understand them clearly and I also want to control the whole saving process. Well, I have this UI component:

[image]

[image]

Are there any solutions to my issue?

Comment: are you asking how the process happens?

Comment: Have you found the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code

```
<?php 

namespace Ced\Cedevent\Ui\DataProvider;

class Grid extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider

{

    public $objectManager;
   
    public $collection;

    public $addFieldStrategies;

    public $addFilterStrategies;

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        \Ced\Cedevent\Model\ResourceModel\Test\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $addFieldStrategies = [],
        array $addFilterStrategies = [],
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {

        if (!$this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $this->getCollection()->load();
        }

        $items = $this->getCollection()->getData();
        
        return [
            'totalRecords' =>  $this->getCollection()->getSize(),
            'items' => array_values($items),
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand fully about UI component,there are so many articles regarding this topic.
    Please read below articles,surely you will understand about UI component

```
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html
https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-a-grid-using-ui-component/
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2016/04/10/magento2-grid-ui-component/
```